# Format value from react-datetime for input type="datetime-local"

Tags: datetime, react-datetime

I use react-datetime

```
    let date = component.props.data.value;
        return <div className={'datetime'}>
            <Datetime locale="ru"                         
                      value={date}
                      onChange={setFilter}
                      closeOnSelect={true}
                      dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'
                      timeFormat='HH:mm'
                      inputProps={{ type: 'datetime-local' }}
            />
        </div>;
```

so when I choose any date and time, I get value like `value:
"2018-05-01 12:00"`. But `input` with `type="datetime-local"` requires `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm` format to show.

[image]

Is there any way to format date the right way?

**UPD**
I've tried to use `moment`

```
let date = moment(component.props.data.value).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
```

But in this case I cannot choose any time, date works ok.

Comment: i have the same problem, i can´t solved error :( @heidel